# how set ClickListener on drawable in Drawable class in android?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, drawable, clicklistener

I have a class that extends from `Drawable`.
I draw some `Views` on it. I have `drawable` that I should set `ClickListener` on it! 
I  searched a lot, and according to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable), we have not listener for this class!

anybody can help me ?! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, which you've already provided,

> A Drawable is a general abstraction for "something that can be drawn."
>
> ...
>
> Unlike a View, a Drawable *does not have* any facility to receive
>   events or otherwise interact with the user.

Since the `View` provides a method to receive click events (`setOnClickListener`) and a method which sets its foreground to a `Drawable` (`setForeground`) why don't you use that?

Comment: Thanks, but this class, is for an old project and all views draw on it, I added one view on it, and should set listener on it, as u said is impossible right?

Comment: *"I added one view on it"*, you mean you added a view to a drawable?

Comment: yes, a class that extends from Drawable was complete and I just edit it a bit, I added Icon (Drawable image) in that class

Comment: Ok maybe by *view* we mean something different. From my perspective I thought that you added a `View` to a `Drawable`, which can't be true since the first is a component and the second is what it gets drawn on the screen.

Comment: right, so it is impossible, should change the design. thank again

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to set a click listener on a Drawable directly. You should put the `Drawable` into an `ImageView` using [`setImageDrawable(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView?#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

From there, you can set a click listener on the `ImageView` with `setOnClickListener` just as you would with any other `View`.